# Request for undeleting a community deleted question

Tags: support

I have asked the question [Distinguishing RPi4 models with USB-C issue and without](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107074/distinguishing-rpi4-models-with-usb-c-issue-and-without) (probably only visible for users with enoughrep) on January 8th.

At that time, it was downvoted and eventually deleted by Community♦ a month later.

To me, it seems that the question is perfectly valid. And I now found [evidence](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flash-kernel/+bug/1854487) that revision 1.2 of the board was already known about in November 2019.

In the meanwhile, we have [revision codes](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/revision-codes/README.md) and even [images](https://www.cnx-software.com/2020/02/24/raspberry-pi-4-rev-1-2-fixes-usb-c-power-issues-improves-sd-card-resilience/) that help identifying the difference.

I would like the question to be undeleted, so I can self-answer it. I already clicked on the "undelete" link, but it needs more votes.

I'm posting this meta question, because I can't post such a long reasoning in the moderator's flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like the question to be undeleted, so I can self-answer it.

Just cut and paste the original into a new Q&A, add your answer, and post that. You should be able to do it all at once -- there is a rep bar below which you have to wait 24 hours, but I think you are past that.

Comment: Done. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108875/distinguishing-rpi4-models-with-usb-c-issue-and-without